# Making Live Messenger pop up on message

Tags: windows-7, windows-live-messenger

Since switching to Windows7, I miss a lot of messages from my contacts in Live Messenger. The reason is, that I don't always have the sound on - and in Win7 the window no longer pops up, when a new contact writes me.

I looked in the options, but I can't seem to find an option, that lets the new windows pop up.

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Messenger --> right click msnmsgr.exe select properties then select compatibility tab and activate "run this program in compatibility mode" and select Windows Vista.It shoulde be OK now for you.

Comment: This seems extremely hacky... But since there was no other answers on how to fix this... :)

Comment: I discovered this while I am trying to close&hide my MSN Live 9 MEssenger on Win 7.

Comment: Quick note: on 64-Bit machines the file is located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Messenger`. Also this fix will allow the notification popup to appear, but it still does not show the full window.